# Xcode label not appearing in frame

Tags: ios, xcode, label, frame

I am trying to make a label programmatically and for some reason it is not appearing. I have declared it on the .h file and this is what I have on the .m:

```
TitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
TitleLabel.frame =CGRectMake(65, 30, 200, 50);
TitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
TitleLabel.alpha = 1;
TitleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BrandonGrotesque-Black" size:23];
TitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
TitleLabel.text = @"TEST";
```

Can anyone help me with this minor issue. Thanks

Comment: Have you added label in view?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the init, do this:
   UILabel *label  = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y,  width ,height)];

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create label ojbect with alloc/init methods:

```
titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

or

```
  titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 30, 200, 50)];
```

And at the end you need to add it on the view:

```
[self.view addSubview:titleLabel];
```

And also, just a little advice - use CamelCase coding style:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase
It is best practice to name instances of classes from lower case, like **titleLabel**, not **TitleLabel**